# Unwanted columns with foreign keys in defaultview

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I'm using `DataSet`, auto-generated (.xsd) from my MySQL database. After filling one of it's `DataTable`, for example `'order_status'`, with appropriate `TableAdapter` and binding `DefaultView` of this table to `DataGrid` in WPF-based GUI as like this

```
var dataSet = new DataSet_dbTV();
var adapter = new order_statusTableAdapter();
adapter.Fill(dataSet.order_status);
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataSet.order_status.DefaultView;
```

I get result with unwanted columns with foreign keys, reffering to this table in my database: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5AJU.png)

SQL query, that assigned to this TableAdapter is

```
SELECT `id`, `Name` FROM `order_status`
```

But if I use straightforward code to get this information from database:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection(@"server=localhost...");
var command = new MySqlCommand("select * from order_status", connection);
var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
DataTable test = new DataTable();
adapter.fill(test);
dataGrid.ItemsSource = test.DefaultView;
```

I obtain expected result.

So, where am I wrong, and how can I get the same expected result with the first approach?